# How Do I Render Table With Meteor Spacebars Template and Row Number For Each Row?

Tags: javascript, meteor, html-table, spacebars

How can I render a table with a meteor spacebars `{{#each}}` in a template and for each row add row number in first column like below:

|     | title header | content header |

| 1   | first title  | first content  |

| 2   | second title | second content |

| 3   | third title  | third content  |

This is my each code now:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>content</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each posts}}
            <tr>
            <td>
                *** need index for each row in this column ***
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ title }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ content }}
            </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to get the array index within the `{{#each}}` or define extra property named `index` myself and `index++` in each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

In your helper that returns the cursor of values, instead of just doing a `collection.find()` do a `collection.find().fetch()` This will give you you an array of objects instead of a cursor. Then simply `.forEach()` through that an add an index key! Or you could just use `collection.map()` and add the key directly to each element as you map the cursor into an array. [Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I think it's work but my collection have many many documents and one extra forEach() only for add index is expensive for me. Is it possible to handle this in template without extra logic?? It's basic task and I think handlebars should be able to do this, but how?

Comment: If you have many documents then you're likely to implement paging anyway in which case you would only be looping over a small number of docs each time. js is extremely fast at such operations.